# Create variable by using range condition and selecting specific variables?

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(DO = c("205145", "587523", '484351', "453475", "456546", "15641334", "465466", '674646', "564635", "65255"),
                   LINHAA2 = c("A150", "B250", "D349", "T980", "R99", "O988", "L99", "Q220", "F530", "P88"),
                   LINHAA3 = c("A445", "K098", "G87", "I10", "A240", "Q88", "V633", "Z100", "I340", "L260"),
                   LINHAA4 = c("K213", "A123", "U876", "X999", "O150", "A765", "Z987", "G543", "P987", "Z100"),
                   LINHAA5 = c("Q098", "K098", "L987", "J988", "C192", "S234", "V123", "P098", "N976", "V199"))
```

Each "LINHAA" variable contais an alphanumeric code. These codes are grouped in 22 chapters (see below). I need to create a variable for each chapter where if any of the codes in "LINHAA" variables belong to said chapter, it will receive 1.

```
data.frame(chapter = 1:22, code = c("A000-B999", "C000-D489", "D500-D899",
                                    "E000-E900", "F000-F999", "G000-G998", 
                                    "H000-H599", "H600-H959", "I000-I999",
                                    "J000-J998", "K000-K938", "L000-L998",
                                    "M000-M999", "N000-N999", "O000-O998",
                                    "P000-P969", "Q000-Q999", "R000-R999",
                                    "S000-T980", "V010-Y989", "Z000-Z999",
                                    "U000-U859"))
```

For example, you can see that the codes "A150" and "A445" belong to the first row. So, when creating the variable CHAPTER1, it will receive 1. CHAPTER2 would receive 0, because none of the codes belong in the range of "C00-D48".

It must create a variable for each of the 22 chapters, even if there aren't any codes that belong to them, so all the variable rows will be filled with 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may check if the package `icd.data`, that deals with ICD-10 codes, is of any help

Comment: Can you be more specific about the chapter restrictions? Should the code D49, if it was available, not be assigned to any chapter?

Comment: It is likely a typo. Chapter 2 of the ICD-10 ends with D49

Comment: Chapter 2 ends in D489 and chapter 3 begins in D500

Comment: also, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73266528/is-there-an-r-function-to-convert-a-dataframe-of-icd10-codes-to-their-respective

Comment: "Chapter 2 ends in D489 and chapter 3 begins in D500" This is already quite different from what you have provided. I would suggest that you first create a dataframe structured like `data.frame(chapter = 1:22, code = c("A000-B999",...)`. Then I can properly help you

Comment: @Ludwig please check update :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution but I think it gets the job done.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(DO = c("205145", "587523", '484351', "453475", "456546", "15641334", "465466", '674646', "564635", "65255"),
                   LINHAA2 = c("A150", "B250", "D349", "T980", "R99", "O988", "L99", "Q220", "F530", "P88"),
                   LINHAA3 = c("A445", "K098", "G87", "I10", "A240", "Q88", "V633", "Z100", "I340", "L260"),
                   LINHAA4 = c("K213", "A123", "U876", "X999", "O150", "A765", "Z987", "G543", "P987", "Z100"),
                   LINHAA5 = c("Q098", "K098", "L987", "J988", "C192", "S234", "V123", "P098", "N976", "V199"))
data <- data %>% pivot_longer(-DO, values_to = "code")

df <- data.frame(chapter = 1:22, code = c("A000-B999", "C000-D489", "D500-D899",
                                    "E000-E900", "F000-F999", "G000-G998", 
                                    "H000-H599", "H600-H959", "I000-I999",
                                    "J000-J998", "K000-K938", "L000-L998",
                                    "M000-M999", "N000-N999", "O000-O998",
                                    "P000-P969", "Q000-Q999", "R000-R999",
                                    "S000-T980", "V010-Y989", "Z000-Z999",
                                    "U000-U859"))
df <- df %>% separate_wider_delim(code, "-", names = c("start","end"))

check_codes <- function(start, end, reference) {
        letter_start <- start %>% str_extract("\\w")
        letter_end <- end %>% str_extract("\\w")
        number_start <- start %>% str_extract("\\d+") %>% as.numeric
        number_end <- end %>% str_extract("\\d+") %>% as.numeric
        
        
        if (letter_start == letter_end) {
                hits <-
                        reference %>% filter(
                                code %>% str_extract("\\w") == letter_start &
                                        code %>%
                                        str_extract("\\d+") %>%
                                        as.numeric %>%
                                        between(number_start, number_end)
                        )
                return(sum(nrow(hits) != 0))
                
        }
        if (letter_start != letter_end) {
                hits <-
                        reference %>% filter((
                                code %>% str_extract("\\w") == letter_start &
                                        code %>%
                                        str_extract("\\d+") %>%
                                        as.numeric %>%
                                        between(number_start, 999)
                        ) | (
                                code %>% str_extract("\\w") == letter_end &
                                        code %>%
                                        str_extract("\\d+") %>%
                                        as.numeric %>%
                                        between(000, number_end)
                        )
                        )
                return(sum(nrow(hits) != 0))
        }
}

df$hit <- mapply(check_codes, df$start, df$end, MoreArgs = list(reference = data), USE.NAMES = FALSE)

df <- df %>% mutate(chapter = chapter, code = paste(start, end, sep = "-"), hit = hit, .keep = "none")

# A tibble: 22 × 3
   chapter   hit code     
     <int> <int> <chr>    
 1       1     1 A000-B999
 2       2     1 C000-D489
 3       3     0 D500-D899
 4       4     0 E000-E900
 5       5     1 F000-F999
 6       6     1 G000-G998
 7       7     0 H000-H599
 8       8     0 H600-H959
 9       9     1 I000-I999
10      10     1 J000-J998
# ℹ 12 more rows
```